# Random import with python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I make a random import ?
For example:

1 probability on 2 to import one or other file

```
import file1 OR
import file2
```

Comment: My guess is that he has functions in different files, and he wants to use the ones from the randomly chosen file (in the manner of CSS files for a Web project).

Comment: It sounds like perhaps you are going about something the wrong way.  Maybe you could explain what you are trying to do and we could provide a better alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
import random
if random.randint(0,1):
    print "Importing file1"
    import file1
else:
    print "Importing file2"
    import file2
```

Comment: I know OP asked for a random module out of 2 precisely, but it would be ugly to code if he wanted to add more possibilities.

Comment: Just a straight forward way :)

Comment: Error with the line of import file1

Comment: @TizianoDan Just a plain import file1 also fails, or?

Answer (score 2):

An approach would be to use `importlib.import_module`.

```py
from random import choice
from importlib import import_module

sources = [
    'file1',
    'file2',
]

source = import_module(choice(sources))
```

Your module would now be available from `source`.

Comment: exceptions.NameError:name 'import_module' is not defined

Comment: You need to import this function, as I did on line 2.

Comment: Where can I find it ? I doesn't find, are you sure it's ok with py 2.7 ?

Comment: Works with me, using Python 2.7 too. Launch a Python prompt, try: `from importlib import import_module` and test it.

Comment: Can you please give me a link to this lib ? It will be much appreciated